# Regular Expression for number and dash

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently I write the regex like this: `/^([\d+]*-)+([\d]*-)+([\d])*$/`

I want the result follow this pattern `00-123-456-789` or `00123456789` (dash between number group or no dash at all)

- not `00-123--457-789`
- or `-00-123-456-789-`
- or `-00123456789-`
- or `00-123-456-789-`

How can I modify the regex to matches the pattern above?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try something like this

```
/^(\d+-?)+\d+$/
```

Comment: This allows any arbitrary length sequence of digits so something like `999999999-99999999999-999999999999999999-0000-0000-000000-000000-0-0000` would be allowed.  The OP's question seemed like it was a more specific pattern of 2 digits, then 3 digits, then 3 digits, then 3 digits.

Comment: This answer will match 00-123456789 or 00-123-456-78, are those patterns allowed?

Comment: @jfriend00 The OP's regex attempt seems to indicate length is not part of the solution (though I could be wrong). From the attempt, it seemed they only wanted to match a number, followed by number-dash combinations (multi numbers, only one dash) and ending in a number. Also, they've indicated this answer is correct ;)

Comment: Your construction is a bit strange, semantically speaking. For example, in the case of a single number group with no separators, your capture group matches all but the last digit. The last digit of the number group is matched by the `\d+` outside the capture group. If the user decides to modify the expression to use capture grouping to return the individual number groups, this would become an issue. Despite this, your solution works perfectly for the problem as posed, and should not be downvoted, at least not without an explanation.

Comment: Yeah, it now appears (based on OP's comments) that there was no particular length of segments requirements.  The question was not very clear on that.

Answer (score 18):

If your question needs the specific segment lengths you specify in your examples, you can use this:

```
/^\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{3}$/
```

This will accept `00-123-456-789`, but will allow for any dashes to be missing.  If you want to allow only for all dashes or no dashes, then you could use this:

```
/^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$|^\d{11}$/
```

which will accept only `00-123-456-789` or `00123456789`, but not allow only some dashes to be missing.

Or, if you meant that you could have any number of digits and any number of single dashes between them, then you could use this:

```
/^\d+(-\d+)*$/
```

Comment: sorry for not accept your answer, but I didn't mean that it 3-number group, but your answer is more accurate than Phil, so I vote up for you.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to have a pattern to match a 10-digit phone number requiring hyphens such as 000-000-0000, and your post helped. I ended with `/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/gm` at https://regex101.com/r/nU0tN6/1

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you wish your regex to stand for strings which consist of a number group followed (optionally) by additional number groups with a `-` separator.

```
\d+      # represents a number group
(-\d+)*  # represents 0 or more additional number groups beginning with "-"
```

So, together with the necessary beginning and end of line assertions, together we have:

```
^\d+(-\d+)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

The following answer will be used to match

00-123-456-789 or 00 123 456 789

/^[\d]{2}[-\s]?[\d]{3}[-\s]?[\d]{3}[-\s]?[\d]{3}$/

If you want only to match hyphen(-) or without hyphen(-)

Then it will do

/^[\d]{2}[-]?[\d]{3}[-]?[\d]{3}[-]?[\d]{3}$/

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to accept ##-###-###-### or ###########, then what you need is something like:

```
/^(([\d+]{2}\-)([\d]{3}\-){2}([\d]{3})|[\d]{11})$/
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

From what have you provided us, this regex `^-?(\d+-?)+$` matches this

```
-00-123-456-789-
-00123456789-
00-123-456-789-
00123456789
```

but doesn't match this:

```
00-123--457-789
```

Breakdown:

- the string can start with a dash (`^-?`)
- it has some digits followed by an optional dash (`\d+-?`)
- the last group can be repeated one or more times (`(\d+-?)+`)
- the string ends (`$`)

Comment: The string cannot start with a dash. The string cannot end with a dash.

Answer (score 0):

@godwin: since I can't add a comment to your post and no one else seems to have responded, let me address at least one issue. At the beginning you have

```
[\d+]{2}\-
```

`\d+` will match one or more digits and you're asking for it to be repeated twice, so the whole segment will match `123456789-`:

- `[\d+]` = `12345678` (greedy matching)
- `[\d+]` = `9`
- `\-` = `-`

You also probably didn't need to escape the dash because it's not inside a group block `"[]"`.