# How to validate password using following conditions?

Tags: javascript

Password should contain

1. At least one uppercase letter
2. At least one lowercase letter
3. At least one digit
4. At least one special symbol
5. should be more than 4 character

I have tried - `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]{6,20}$`

Comment: I have tried different regular expressions but couldn't get the expression which exactly checks the above conditions

Comment: can you paste those so we can help?

Comment: @John post that regex...

Comment: ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]{6,20}$

Answer (score 25):

You don't need some big monster single regular expression, which would probably involve arcana such as lookaheads, and be hard to maintain as new conditions were added. All you need is

```
function validatePassword(pw) {

    return /[A-Z]/       .test(pw) &&
           /[a-z]/       .test(pw) &&
           /[0-9]/       .test(pw) &&
           /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(pw) &&
           pw.length > 4;

}
```

Comment: "You don't need a regular expression", but you posted a regular expression, and several at that ;)

Comment: function validatePassword(email) { 
    var re =/A-Z/.test(pw) && /a-z/.test(pw) && /0-9/.test(pw) && /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(pw) && pw.length >=4;
    return re.test(email);
}

Comment: You're creating a regexp and setting it equal to a boolean value giving the result of password validation, then trying to use that regexp to test against email, so it's not surprising it's not working.

Comment: +1 for such a simple, readable, obvious-what-it-does, easy-to-maintain solution even for regex beginners.

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(\W|_)).{5,}$
```

You can use the above regex with lookahead and you can *easily* append any other criteria if required in 
future. You're basically checking if each of your criteria is present by lookaheads.

```
if(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(\W|_)).{5,}$/.test(pwd)){
   // valid password
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/cG9vB7/2)

Comment: I've never understood who thinks this is actually readable code.

Comment: @jfriend00 regex isn't made to be readable. They're unreadable by nature

Comment: @jfriend00 this may be unreadable, but it's Regex so it's not meant to be readable, it's functional, it's efficient, and it works. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  Readable code is very important.  So long, complicated regex expressions often don't meet that requirement and thus I do not consider good solutions or good code.  Good code should be correct, reliable, easily understandable and maintainable (by others) and have appropriate performance in approximately that order.  A very complicated regex doesn't meet at least one of those requirements.  Compare the readability of this to torazaburo's answer and there's no contest.

Comment: @jfriend00 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292965/regular-expression-for-number-and-dash/8293009#8293009 and if you can see, OP himself used lookaheads, he *knows* what they do, torazaburo has answered it in his style, while I used lookaheads, after seeing his answer

Comment: Well, in general I agree that big regexps are hard to read and maintain, but one could also use XRegExp, which allows you to comment them, add white space, and write them on multiple lines.

Comment: @AmitJoki One particularly stupid set of password rules I encountered recently was "must not contain the same character consecutively". How would that be done? Using simple regexps, it's just another test, `!/(.)\1/.test(pw)`. That same set of password rules says "must not contain first three or last two characters of user name". How would I do that? At the end of the day, what was the point in monolithic regexps again, other than displays of virtuosity?

Comment: @torazaburo your answer is good and I accept that and up-votes too suggest the same, but if someone goes on arguing about that, and perhaps I would have checked that alone and use the rest, `(!/(.)\1/.test(pw) && /myRegex/.test(pw))`, OP will accept your answer, deal done and I've added yet another method of solving the problem, those who need it can use and rest can use yours, what's the big deal?

Comment: @torazaburo if you think this answer is utterly useless, I will delete it without taking anything to heart...

Comment: @AmitJoki No, actually I think your answer is interesting and creative, and I think everyone should know how to use look-aheads.

Answer (score 1):

A bit enhanced version of great answer given by @user663031

```js
var errors = {
   uppercase: { regex: /[A-Z]/, description: 'At least one uppercase letter' },
   lowercase: { regex: /[a-z]/, description: 'At least one lowercase letter' },
   digit: { regex: /[0-9]/, description: 'At least one digit' },
   special: { regex: /[^A-Za-z0-9]/, description: 'At least one special symbol' },
   length: { test: e => e.length > 2, description: 'Should be more than 2 characters' },
};

function validatePassword(e) {
  return Object.entries(errors).flatMap(([name, { test, regex, description }]) => {
    const isValid = test ? test(e) : regex.test(e);
    return isValid ? [] : { description, name };
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(validatePassword('a'),null,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check each condition separated without regular expressions. The idea is check every condition (lowercase, uppercase, length, number) and change a switch

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/61kjmat6/1/)

HTML

```
<label for="password">Type password</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="button" name="check" id="check" onclick="check()" value="Check password!"/>

<p id="respuesta"></p>
```

Javascript

```
checkbt = document.getElementById("check");
passtxt = document.getElementById("password");
respuesta = document.getElementById("respuesta");

check = function(){
    texto = passtxt.value.trim();
    uppercase = false;
    lowercase = false;
    number = false;
    lenght = false;
    //uppercase letter    
    for (i=0; i< texto.length; i++){
        if (texto[i] == texto[i].toUpperCase()){
            uppercase = true;
            break;
        } else {
            uppercase = false;
        }
    }
//lowercase
        for (i=0; i< texto.length; i++){
            if (texto[i] == texto[i].toLowerCase()){
                lowercase = true;
                break;
            } else {
                lowercase = false;
            }
        }

    //number
        for (i=0; i< texto.length; i++){
            if (!isNaN(texto[i])){
                number = true;
                break;
            } else {
                number = false;
            }
        }    


    if (texto.length < 6){
        lenght = false;
    } else {
        lenght = true;
    }

    if (lowercase && uppercase && number && lenght){
        respuesta.innerHTML = "Password is good";    
    } else {
        respuesta.innerHTML = "Password is bad <br />" +
        "lowercase: " + boolstr(lowercase) + "<br />"+
        "uppercase: " + boolstr(uppercase) + "<br />"+
        "number: " + boolstr(number) + "<br />"+
        "lenght: " + boolstr(lenght) + "<br />";
    }

}

function boolstr(val){
if (val == true)
    return "true";
    else
    return "false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below regular expression should work for you...

```
var pattern = /^(?=.{5,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\W])/
```

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" id="pass" />
<input type="button" id="btnpass" value="Test" />
```

**jQuery code**

```
var pattern = /^(?=.{5,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\W])/

$("#btnpass").click(function(){
    var checkval = pattern.test($("#pass").val());

    if(!checkval) {
        alert("Invalid password");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ty72wn1g/4/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. For example, `A1#` validates. The whole regexp is just lookaheads.

Comment: Thanks for testing my regex. Above regex is working now.