# JavaScript input validation: numbers and dash

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm trying to validate an input in JavaScript. The format must be this: integer+dash+integer. There can be space between the integer and the dash, but the integer must be in numeric format (no 'e' allowed) and the first number is smaller than the second. So examples can be: 1-100, 1- 100, or 1 - 100. I'm not familiar with regular expressions but I feel that using regex should be more efficient to do this. Can anyone show me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: There are some great online resources for learning regexes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: this question is off topic as a "gimme the codez" - instead show what you tried and we will help you if you failed - just searching for integer and dash already comes up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292965/regular-expression-for-number-and-dash

Comment: Try something like this `/^(\d*\-\d*)\w+` in your JavaScript `match()`

Comment: what makes you think a regex is the way to go? The deal with the second number being larger than the first makes it less simple to use a regex, and regex should mostly only be used when they can be simple.
`let nums = str.split('-').map(s => s*1); let valid = nums.length === 2 && nums[0] > 0 && nums[0] <= 100 && nums[1] >0 && nums[1] <= 100 && nums[0] < nums[1]`..... there are cleaner ways to do this; like not in a comment on SO.

Comment: @Catalyst - do noobs a favour and use ecma262 instead of ES6 when you give "simple examples" - your script needs IE11+ to run. `var nums = str.split("-"); return (nums.length==2 && nums[1]-nums[0] >0)` is simpler

Comment: @mplungjan my bad. I'm mostly backend javascript and I forget. (I also forget math exists on occasion).

Comment: @mplungjan don't forget to check that things are <= 100 though

Comment: The 100 seems to be an example - but `var nums = str.split("-"); return (nums.length===2 nums[1] <= 100 && nums[1]-nums[0] >0)` - still missing the test for 10e2 or something

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function validateMyInt(s) {
  var reg = /^(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)$/;
  var match = reg.exec(s);
  if(match) {
    var a = parseInt(match[1],10), b = parseInt(match[2],10);
    return a < b;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(validateMyInt("1-100"));
console.log(validateMyInt("1- 100"));
console.log(validateMyInt("1 -100"));
console.log(validateMyInt("100-1"));
```

Comment: `{0,}` is a mouthful when there is `*`.